# Reblog wordpress.com posts on self hosted

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I'm currently collaborating to a wordress.com blog and would like to use the reblog feature to mirror my posts there to my main blog that is a self hosted wordpress installation.

My understanding is that this is only possible within wordpress.com so I searched for some plugins to accomplish this and the closest I came to it is the "Press This" feature, but it's not a good solution because it's mostly copying and pasting the text from the other post and it seems to fail to import links, youtube videos and other things.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/ or another RSS aggregator.

Comment: Neat, I'll give it a try. Can this be used to mirror only some posts from the rss feed?

Comment: Read the docs. If you only want some posts, you will probably have to import them by category, or go back to manual entry.